# What is The JDBC connect string for connecting to mysql when SSL certificates are required?

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud SQL instance in which I have to enable that SSL certificates are require to connect.

The equivalent MySQL command for connecting to my instance is this

```
mysql --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem --host=[INSTANCE_IP] --user=root --password
```

Now I need an equivalent JDBC connection string for the same.
What Addition parameter should a add to my correct JDBC string?

```
jdbc:mysql://<server_ip>:3306/<db_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Cloud SQL Java Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md), you don't need any configuration - SSL/TLS happens automatically.

If you prefer, you can also connect the same way with a regular MySQL database, which involves creating a Java keystore. [This blogpost has an example of how to do so.](https://www.querypie.com/blog/mysql-ssl-connection-using-jdbc/)

Comment: the CloudSQL Java Connector doesn't seem to have a way to pass in a PEM cert...nothing in their docs either.

Comment: @kenyee the Cloud SQL Java connector automates the creation and handling of the certs for you - you don't need to pass in a PEM cert because it's using the Admin API to generate and use it for encryption automatically.